# Error creating a spatial database. ERROR : could not load library "/usr/pgsql-9.1/lib/rtpostgis-2.0.so"

Tags: postgis, postgresql, spatial-database, postgis-2.0

I am running `PostgreSQL 9.1` with `Postgis 2.0` on `Fedora 15`.

When trying to install the raster support,

```
psql -d mydb -f rtpostgis.sql -v ON_ERROR_STOP=1
```

I get the following error

```
psql:rtpostgis.sql:46: ERROR:  
     could not load library "/usr/pgsql-9.1/lib/rtpostgis-2.0.so": libhdf5.so.6: 
     cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

A `locate libhdf5.so.6` gives the following paths.

```
/usr/lib64/mpich2/lib/libhdf5.so.6
/usr/lib64/mpich2/lib/libhdf5.so.6.0.4
```

Reinstalling the `GDAL` from the repositories did not solve the problem. The version of the installed `GDAL`.

```
gdal.x86_64                                1.7.3-14.fc15                @updates
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll want to check that /etc/ld.so.conf has a referencence to the path /usr/lib64/mpich2/lib.  If you add the path to ldo.so.conf, make sure to run ldconfig.  You can then see what is in the ld cache using "ldconfig -p".

Comment: `/etc/ld.so.conf` had  `include ld.so.conf.d/*.conf` one of the file was `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/atlas-x8664.conf` which contained  `/usr/lib64/atlas`. A `ldconfig -p | grep libhdf5` did not return anything. So I created a file `gdal.conf` and added the path `/usr/lib64/mpich2/lib`. Ran `ldconfig`. Now, `ldconfig -p | grep libhdf5` had the paths to `llibhdf5` files. After doing this, postgis raster suppot installation went smoothly. Thanks you for the input.

Answer (score 1):

From my article:
https://fmdojo.wordpress.com/2017/01/10/postgis-create-extension-error-cannot-find-libhdf5-so-6/

```
# find the lib if exist in OS filesystem
# returns: /usr/lib64/openmpi/lib/libhdf5.so.6
find / -name libhdf5.so.6

cd /etc/ld.so.conf.d/
nano postgis-fix.conf

# add to file:
/usr/lib64/openmpi/lib/

# Reload libs configs:
ldconfig

# check the lib:
ldconfig -p | grep libhdf5
```