# PostGIS ERROR: could not load library "/usr/lib/postgresql91/lib64/postgis-2.0.so"

Tags: postgis, postgresql

OS is openSUSE 12.1, PostgreSQL - 9.1, PostGIS - 2.0. Postgre/PostGIS are installed from Application:Geo repository.

After recent updates when I try to connect to my database I get the following error:

```
    ERROR:  could not load library "/usr/lib/postgresql91/lib64/postgis-2.0.so":
 /usr/lib/postgresql91/lib64/postgis-2.0.so: undefined symbol: pj_get_spheroid_defn
```

I searched the web for this error ([hint-1](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/31177/error-creating-a-spatial-database-error-could-not-load-library-usr-pgsql-9), [hint-2](http://answerpot.com/showthread.php?3980453-install%20template%20postgis%202)) and seems that it may have something to do with ld.so.config (or ldconfig command). But I can't figure out what I have to do in my case.

Comment: a recent version of proj (>= 4.8) is needed. What does `proj --version` and/or `ldd \`which proj\`` show?

Comment: @MikeToews, my proj version is 4.7.1. Looks like I need to update it.

Comment: I have installed proj 4.8 from their official site.
But still when I do proj --verion it shows me > `Rel. 4.7.1, 23 September 2009` How can I upgrade it to 4.8. I am out of any ideas :( I am using Ubuntu 12.4 Thanks
Mo.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks to MikeToews I was able to fix this issue. PostGIS 2.0 in openSUSE depends on `libproj0` and its version must be >=4.8. Somehow package manager didn't notify me about new version available for the `libproj0` so I checked its newer version manually via Yast in "Versions" tab. After an update I'm able to operate database normally.

Comment: this is not true.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe the chosen answer has anything to do with the problem,

## What happened

1. Postgre/PostGIS are installed from Application:Geo repository.
2. OS is openSUSE

You installed a new version of PostGIS built against a version of proj you don't have. Your proj is likely provided by OpenSUSE. You need to install the version of proj from the [Application:Geo repository](https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/Application:/Geo/SLE_12_Backports/x86_64/), or the version of PostGIS from the mainline OpenSUSE repository. This is a dependency-client mismatch. You should file a bug in SUSE if the problem persists.

It's not that PostGIS doesn't work on old versions of proj. It's that [SUSE is *ONLY* building PostGIS against newer versions](https://build.opensuse.org/package/view_file/Application:Geo:Staging/postgresql92-postgis/postgresql93-postgis.changes?expand=1) so you require one.

## PostGIS and old proj

[From a bug report filed two years ago](https://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/ticket/3274?cversion=0&cnum_hist=1),

> So basically PostGIS can work also with older Proj4 versions, but it needs to know at compile time.
>
> It then looks like watsonta's binary was built against Proj 4.8 but was running against a previous version. Very likely a bug in the binary package, or its dependencies (proj-4.8+ being a dependency of the *binary* postgis as built by the packager).

I think that's the problem. You built against a newer versoin of proj than you have installed. Upgrading the install to the version you built agianst is just one way to fix the problem.

You can see that [function called here](https://github.com/postgis/postgis/blob/741b88eda71c80701366dffecd7fa665ee47060c/libpgcommon/lwgeom_transform.c#L746) and it's protected by an [`if`](https://github.com/postgis/postgis/blob/741b88eda71c80701366dffecd7fa665ee47060c/libpgcommon/lwgeom_transform.c#L743).

```
#if POSTGIS_PROJ_VERSION >= 48
```

If that's not working you've got another problem. It's [provided by the build system](https://github.com/postgis/postgis/blob/c9ba893dab1a6910ce6bedc7662c955be1a074f8/configure.ac#L828) in a [10 year old macro](https://github.com/postgis/postgis/blob/bd3177743db5cb786deb05d7327f39a5cec2daf6/macros/ac_proj4_version.m4#L33)

Answer (score -1):

mmrs151. To upgrade from proj version 4.7 to proj 4.8 on Ubuntu 13.04. At least it helped me solve the same problem.

> $ sudo apt-get upgrade libproj-dev

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on your answer? How does it solve the OP's problem?

Comment: This answer is useless - openSUSE doesn't use apt.

Comment: The answer was meant for mmrs151.